# Proof inside nested constructor of recursive type

Tags: idris

I am having some trouble with the code below. Essentially I want to create a slice type. The motivation comes from Python, where a slice is `[start:end:step]`, used for slicing a sublist out of a list. This is conceptually the same as a sequence of indices `[start, start+step, start+2*step, ..., end]`.

The way I've tried to capture it is `Slice n` can be applied to a `Vect (n+m) a`. The basic constructor `FwdS` will create a slice with a non-zero step (proof stepNZ). The `SLen` constructor will increment an existing slice's `Vect` size requirement by its `step` (computed using `stepOf`). Similarly `SStart` increments a slice's `Vect` size requirement by 1.

Then the final value conceptually corresponds to:

```
start := # of SStart in slice
stop  := start + (# of SLen) * step 
step  := constructor argument in FwdS
```

If the slice is `[start:stop:step]`.

```
mutual
  data Slice : Nat -> Type where
    FwdS   : (step : Nat) -> {stepNZ  : Not (step = Z)} -> Slice Z
    SLen   : (x : Slice len) -> Slice (len + (stepOf x))
    SStart : Slice len -> Slice (S len)

  stepOf : Slice n -> Nat
  stepOf (FwdS step)    = step
  stepOf (SLen slice)   = stepOf slice
  stepOf (SStart slice) = stepOf slice

length : Slice n -> Nat
length (FwdS step )   = Z
length (SLen slice)   = let step = stepOf slice
                            len  = length slice
                         in len + step
length (SStart slice) = length slice

select : (slice: Slice n) -> Vect (n+m) a ->  Vect (length slice) a
select (FwdS step) xs           = []
select (SStart slice) (x :: xs) = select slice xs
select (SLen slice) (xs)        = ?trouble
```

The trouble is in the last pattern. I'm not sure what the issue is - if I try to case split on `xs` I get both `[]` and `(_::_)` impossible. Ideally I'd like to have that case read something like this:

```
select (SLen slice) (x :: xs) = let rec = drop (stepOf slice) (x::xs)
                                 in x :: (select slice rec)
```

and have Idris recognize that if the first argument is an `SLen` constructor, the second argument cannot be `[]`. My intuition is that at the `SLen` level, Idris does not understand it already has a proof that `stepOf slice` is not `Z`. But I'm not sure how to test that idea.

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition is that at the SLen level, Idris does not understand it already has a proof that stepOf slice is not Z.

You are right. With `:t trouble` you see that the compiler doesn't have enough information to infer that `(plus (plus len (stepOf slice)) m)` is not 0.

```
  a : Type
  m : Nat
  len : Nat
  slice : Slice len
  xs : Vect (plus (plus len (stepOf slice)) m) a
--------------------------------------
trouble : Vect (plus (length slice) (stepOf slice)) a
```

You would have to solve two problems: get a proof that `stepOf slice` is `S k` for some `k` like `getPrf : (x : Slice n) -> (k ** stepOf x = (S k))`, then rewrite `Vect (plus (plus len (stepOf slice)) m) a` to something like `Vect (S (plus k (plus len m))) a` so the compiler can at least know that this `xs` is not empty. But it doesn't get easier from thereon. :-)

Basically whenever you have a function where you use functions in the arguments, you probably can rewrite those informations into the type. Like `select` with `length slice` or `SLen` with `stepOf x`. Here is an example implementation:

```
data Slice : (start : Nat) -> (len : Nat) -> (step : Nat) -> (cnt : Nat) -> Type where
  FwdS : (step : Nat) -> Slice Z Z step Z
  SLen : Slice Z len step cnt -> Slice Z (S step + len) step (S cnt)
  SStart : Slice start len step cnt -> Slice (S start) len step cnt
```

You gain a lot from this: you can access the parameters `len` and `step` directly without proving the functions `length` and `stepOf` first. Also you can have better control about your allowed data. For example, in your definiton `SLen $ SStart $ SLen $ SStart $ FwdS 3` would have been valid, mixing steps and start increments.

`select` could look like this:

```
select : Slice start len step cnt -> Vect (start + len + m) a -> Vect cnt a
select (FwdS k) xs = []
select (SStart s) (x :: xs) = select s xs
select (SLen s) [] impossible
select (SLen s {step} {len} {cnt}) (x::xs) {m} {a} =
  let is = replace (sym $ plusAssociative step len m) xs {P=\t => Vect t a} in
  (x :: select s (drop step is))
```

If you want an exercise with proving, you could try to implement `select : Slice start len step cnt -> Vect (len + start + m) a -> Vect cnt a`, so switching `start + len`.

And getting two elements starting at 1 in steps of 4:

```
> select (SStart $ SLen $ SLen $ FwdS 3) [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
[1, 5] : Vect 2 Integer
```